# Using template specialization in C++

Tags: c++, templates

How can I write a function using template specialization that has 2 different input types and an output type:

```
template <class input1, class input2, class output>
```

and return the sum of the 2 numbers (integers/doubles). However, if I get 2 integers I want to return an integer type but for any other combinations of integer and double I'll always return double.

I am trying to do that without using directly the '+' operator but having the next functions instead:

```
double add_double_double(double a, double b) {return (a+b);}
double add_int_double(int a, double b) {return ((double)(a)+b);}
int   add_int_int(int a, int b) {return (a+b);}
```

Comment: It seems to me you're describing the built-in operator + ?

Comment: @icecrime: Suppose the question was, "how do I write a template function which has the same return type as the type of the expression `a+b`, a and b being its inputs"? The answer in C++0x is to use `decltype` and a trailing return type, but what about C++03?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible for the return type of a function template to depend on the types of the template parameters. In your case, you can do something similar to:

```
template <typename L, typename R>
struct sum_traits { typedef double return_type; };

template <>
struct sum_traits<int, int> { typedef int return_type; };

template <typename L, typename R>
typename sum_traits<L, R>::return_type
sum(L l, R r) { 
  typedef typename sum_traits<L, R>::return_type ret_t;
  return ret_t(l) + ret_t(r); 
}
```

I don't think the explicit casts to `ret_t` are ever actually needed *in this case*, but it demonstrates some more of the technique.

This handles just ints, but the idea can easily be generalized to handle more complex cases.

Comment: Note that as you get more complex traits, you can further delegate the type calculations.

Answer (score 5):

If you can use C++0x, you could do this:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto add(T lhs, U rhs) -> decltype(lhs+rhs)
{
    return lhs+rhs;
}
```

Comment: Read up on the changes brought about in the new C++ spec (the spec is called C++0x). In essence it is saying: the type of add() is whatever the type of (lhs+rhs) is (what "-> decltype" does), and add() returns that type (what "auto" does). Given the compiler knows what type T and U are, and assuming "+" is defined for a T + a U, then the compiler knows what type (lhs+rhs) is - because "+" is defined. So the code is telling the compiler to use that info and produce the correct output.

Comment: @user550413: C++0x is the codename for the next version of C++, which will (hopefully) be finalized this year. Most modern compilers have partial support for it already. The code @Polybos posted simply defines a function where the return type is "whatever the type of `lhs+rhs` is". `decltype` evaluates to the type of the expression inside the parentheses, and `auto` in this context just means that the return type is specified at the end of the line, after a `->` instead of before the function name.

Comment: C++0x allows you to define a function `F` which returns a value of type `R` as `auto F(...) -> R` instead of the traditional `R F(...)`. And the reason for this new syntax is basically to allow `decltype` to be used in the manner shown here.

Comment: And this auto, and -> decltype stuff might look suspiciously like DWIM until you consider that a template function might be asked to deal with a large set of template types... without this C++0x method you'd have to write a different specialization of the template function for each case (as I did in my answer). What if there are 10 possible type for each input and 10 possible type for the output! With the C++0x approach you just have to ensure (lhs+rhs) operation is defined for each pair of types T and U... but you would have to do that with prior versions of C++ anyway.

Comment: "you'd have to write a different specialization of the template function for each case" - or perhaps use TMP to create a meta-function mapping a pair of types (the inputs) to a single type (the output). Then you'd do something like `template <typename T, U> my_tmp_stuff<T,U>::type add(T t, U u);`. The question then is how much of `my_tmp_stuff` can be systematic, and how much has to be handled in special cases.

Answer (score 4):

Don’t use template specialization. Use overloading instead. Specializing functions is complicated and rarely needed:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
double sum(T1 a, T2 b) { return a + b; }

int sum(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```

The second version will be called if and only if both arguments are `int`; otherwise, the first version will be called.

Comment: `long` is an integer type. If I call this with two `long` arguments, do I get the return type the questioner wants? (Not that I know what return type the questioner wants in that case)

Comment: @Steve: from the question it sounded as if the OP was only interested in `int`, not other integer types.

Comment: @Konrad: Apparently, it enters the first sum even if I send 2 integers.

Comment: @user: It doesn’t on my compiler (g++ 4.5) – I just tested.

Comment: I think this kind of dodges the issue. Ideally, I think the OP would like a function template which works with *any* type, and just deduces the correct return type (as done trivially with `decltype` in C++0x). So overloading isn't really a good solution as it only works for a bounded set of types (and you have to write a number of overloads, instead of a single general version). Of course overloading is generally preferable to template specialization, but specialization isn't really called for here anyway, I think.

Comment: @jalf: as I have already answered to Steve, I understood the question differently – but you are probably right.

Comment: @Konrad: I guess I read too much into "return an integer type". The questioner's examples suggest it is just `int`

Comment: it is a bit unclear though (not least because the OP explicitly mentions template specialization), so your interpretation might be right. In any case, I agree entirely on overloading > specialization. :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you need:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class input1, class input2, class output> output add(input1 n1, input2 n2) {
   return (output) n1 + (output) n2;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

   cout << add<int, int, int>(1,1) << endl;
   cout << add<float, int, float>(1.1f,1) << endl;
   cout << add<int, float, float>(1,1.1f) << endl;
   cout << add<float, float, int>(1.1f,1.1f) << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
quad: > ./a.out 
2
2.1
2.1
2
Sun 09 Jan 2011 12:57:57 PM MST

quad: >
```

Comment: Oops, where you see 'float' above, just imagine you actually see 'double'.

Comment: Almost, but I am trying (asked to) to do that without the '+' operator. Got 3 functions instead of the '+' (See above: EDITED)

Comment: Then I don't understand what you want. 'sum' means addition, yes? You will need an operator to do the addition, at least if you are dealing with integral or floating point data.

Comment: Yes, but not directly. Imagine you don't have any access to the '+' operator but only to the 3 adding functions above.

Comment: I dunno, man, maybe overload '-' to do addition? Why don't you have '+', was it overloaded elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question lies in Chapter 15 of [C++ templates](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/tmplbook.html) book. This chapter has an [accumulator example](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/traits/accum6.hpp.html) which addresses your question. Further down the chapter it will talk about promotion traits where it will address the problem of adding two different types and also address type promotion.